# index annotation with morphia does not work

Tags: mongodb, playframework-2.0, morphia, mongodb-java

I'm pretty new to morphia and struggling with getting the index annotation to work. I'm creating the datasource in a static block and calling ensureIndexes in the same block, but it fails to apply the indexes. If I put the line right before I save the object it works.

By the way,I'm using playframework 2 with Java.

```
public class MongoService {
static private MongoClient mongoClient = null;
static Datastore ds = null;

static {
    MorphiaLoggerFactory.reset();
    MorphiaLoggerFactory.registerLogger(com.google.code.morphia.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogrImplFactory.class);
    try {
        Logger.debug("mongo uri:" + mongoUri);
        MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(mongoUri);
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
        ds =  new Morphia().createDatastore(mongoClient, dbname);
        ds.ensureIndexes();
        ds.ensureCaps();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        Logger.error("exception:" + e.fillInStackTrace());
    }

}

public static User insertUser(User user) {
    //ds.ensureIndexes(); //UNCOMMENTING THIS LINE MAKES IT WORK
    ds.save(user);
    return user;
}
```

This is the implementation of the user class:

```
@Entity(noClassnameStored = true)
public class User {

@Id private ObjectId id;

@Indexed(value=IndexDirection.ASC, name="email", unique=true, dropDups=true) 
public String email; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a conflict between package loader that Morphia is using and the one that play framework is trying to use, I could not find the exact problem but as a workaround I am mapping each object one by one and that seems to be working

```
 morph.map(User.class);
 morph.map(Address.class);
 . 
 . 
 .
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer…it took me a while to figure out what is going on. A more explicit solution along the lines of what you are doing is to ensure indices on all class that have @Indexed annotation like this: ds.ensureIndexes(User.class, false). The last parameter specifies whether index building occurs in background.

Answer (score 4):

You need to map your entity classes - either by package or by class:

```
ds = new Morphia().mapPackage("com.test.entities").createDatastore(mongoClient, dbname);
```

Comment: i added following line ds = new Morphia().mapPackage("models").createDatastore(mongoClient, dbname);  models is the default play package for models and where my User class is but i get this exception:com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Could not get map classes from package models

Comment: and when i add this line:    ds = new Morphia().map(User.class).createDatastore(mongoClient, dbname); the problem exists, morphia is not considering the idnexes

Comment: I've never worked with Play, so I'm not sure how to fix this. I assume ``new Morphia().mapPackage(YourEntity.class.getPackage().getName()).createDatastore(mongoClient, dbname);`` doesn't work as well?

Comment: my guess is there is something wrong with the class loader that cannot find the package, it must be a conflict between package loader that play uses and the one that morphia is trying to user

Comment: Using mapPackage and then using datastore.ensureIndexes() solved my problem. (Though I'm not using playframework.)

Comment: I use play framework and no problem with this, solved my issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is my code in Play, and it works. Please try:

```
 modelClass = Class.forName(model, true, app.classloader());
 morphia.map(modelClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although for OP this wasn't the issue, I found that even though the @Entity class decorator is optional, if it's left out then field-level indexes don't get created by Morphia.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by this form:

```
public void create(Producto p) {
        Morphia m =new Morphia();
        Datastore ds = m.mapPackage("ec.edu.espe.as.model.Producto").createDatastore(new MongoClient(), "productoPrueba");              
        DBObject dbo = m.toDBObject(p);        
        ds.ensureIndexes();
        ds.getCollection(Producto.class).insert(dbo);
    }
```

I mean, make the ensureIndexes just before insert